# How to store datetime from custom meta box so that it can be sorted by

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a custom meta boxe on a custom post type that has two date time fields. I will need to sort by these fields and also return posts that contain a date between two dates.

Will WordPress automatically store these dates as varchars? What will be the best format to save the date in so that I can query them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post meta is stored in [the `wp_postmeta` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta).  Values are stored as longtext, not as dates or integers.

So your safest bet is to store these datetime fields as Unix timestamps.  Then you can sort them using a meta query.